# How to return from JUnit test to main method if part of test takes too long

Tags: java, testing, junit, timeout

I try to run junit from my `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws ClassNotFoundException, 
       IOException {
  //...
  logger.debug("className " + className + "methodName " + methodName);

  Request request = Request.method(Class.forName(className), methodName);
  return new JUnitCore().run(request);
}
```

I have an E2E test with 10 commands (say). It is run by JUnit and I want to limit the run time of commands 3-5 to *X* millis (where *X* is determined at run time). If it runs longer than *X* I want to return to the `main()` and print something.

I have tried `System.exit()` but it closes the whole application. I tried:

```
public void setTimeOut(String criticalBlockTimeOutMilli) {
    if (criticalBlockTimeOutMilli != null) {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                E2eResult e2eResult = E2eResult.getInstance();
                e2eResult.status = E2eStatus.TIMEOUT;
                //System.exit(2);
            }
        };
        new Timer().schedule(timerTask, Long.parseLong(criticalBlockTimeOutMilli));
    }
}

public void setTimeOut(final Thread thread, String criticalBlockTimeOutMilli) {
    if (criticalBlockTimeOutMilli != null) {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                E2eResult e2eResult = E2eResult.getInstance();
                e2eResult.status = E2eStatus.TIMEOUT;
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        };
        new Timer().schedule(timerTask, Long.parseLong(criticalBlockTimeOutMilli));
    }
}
```

but the main thread continues to run the test even if exceeds the limit. What would you suggest?

Comment: You should use an `ExecutorService` instead of `Timer`s

Comment: can you please provide an example because I still cannot see how it helps

Comment: It would have been better if you'd edited [your original question on this subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502750/how-to-pass-a-result-from-junit-to-my-main-method), rather than posting a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Unit testing might not be the best approach to solving this sort of performance testing. However, if there's some reason this must be done, read on...*

Use an `ExecutorService` to run the commands you want, with a given timeout. If the timeout expires, throw your own exception that you can catch in your main thread:

```
@Test
public void yourTest() throws Exception {

  // Do commands 1-2

  ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
  Future<Void> result = service.submit(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
      // call commands 3-5
      return null;
    }
  });

  try {
    result.get(42, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  } catch (TimeoutException e) {
    throw new YourOwnException();
  }

  service.shutdown();

  // Do commands 6-10
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One fairly simple mechanism is to use a `BlockingQueue` to indicate that the test completed. If you find it didn't you can then `interrupt` it. This will only work if the test correctly responds to being interrupted.

```
// Send FINISHED down this queue when test completes.
final BlockingQueue<Object> finished = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);
// FINISHED cookie.
static final Object FINISHED = new Object();

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread test = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do your stuff.
            // ...
            // Signal we finished.
            finished.add(FINISHED);
        }
    });
    // Start the test in it's own thread.
    test.start();
    try {
        // Wait for your time.
        if (FINISHED == finished.poll(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            // It completed! No problems.
        } else {
            // It hasn't finished! Interrupt it.
            test.interrupt();
        };
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        // We were interrupted! Do something.
        test.interrupt();
        // Rethrow it.
        throw(ex);
    }
}
```

You can extend this mechanism by adding a "Started" message too so you can ensure that the test thread gets at least a chance to run.

Comment: Yes, this `if (FINISHED == finished.poll(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {` will work since you're always using the String constant, but still it bugs me to see Strings compares with `==`, since if the code is changed in a way that does not use constants (which you know that someone will do, based on Murphy's law), the code is sunk.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Changed to `Object` for slightly betterness. I would probably move it to `enum Status {STARTED,FINISHED}` in real code for best type safety but that starts getting overly complex in an answer.

Comment: but I want to limit the execution time of just some commands not the test as a whole.

Comment: I know interrupt only raise a flag in the interrupted thread, not stop its current task

Comment: @user1065869 - Re: *but I want...* - Then do this only for those commands. Re: *I know interrupt...* - That is what I meant by *This will only work if the test correctly responds to being interrupted.*